# History API - replaceState on a previous page?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

Wondering if I can use the HTML5 history API's `replaceState()` method (or something similar) to change the state of a previously visited page (as opposed to the current page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research...

Strictly speaking, you can't use `replaceState()` to change where back navigation will go to. However, you can listen to the `popstate` event and navigate accordingly.

Additional documentation:

[Mozilla's guide to 'Manipulating the browser history'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

[Mozilla's window.history documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.history)